# GTM - keep track of last processed dataLayer item

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a custom javascript GTM tag that goes through items in dataLayer and makes some processing based on the items. The tag is triggered on a custom event.

I need to keep track of which items in the data layer have already been there before and which of them are new items that need to be processed. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

One solution would be to store a global variable, for example
`window.tagLastProcessedItemIndex`
but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: The logic is the same. Keep in global variable or localStorage to keep track

Answer (score 0):

First of all, about 95% of all cases when one iterates through the DL are either mistakes or an attempt to fix a trivial front-end misimplementation with an awkward loop with the N complexity.

As a professional analytics implementation expert working mostly for enterprise corps and analytics agencies, I never needed to iterate through a DL manually. Moreover, it is many times that I had to reimplement someone else's iteration through the DL.

Having said that, if you're sure there's no better way to do what you need to do, then yes, you'd need to store the last processed index. Whether you do it in a JS var, cookie, or the DL itself depends on your particular situation. You could also flush the DL as an alternative using something like:

```
google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}].dataLayer.reset();
```

Again, depends on your particular case. Usually preserving your DL is a good idea, so people rarely reset it like that.